# How to escape string data passed from laravel to vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm setting up a new website and I'd like to send data from the Laravel blade template to the Vue.js front end.

I've tried passing the php property into an html proprerty I can access from vue and this works with simple strings.

```
<div id="paragraphs" originaldata="{!! $band->paragraphs !!}">
...
mounted: function() {
    this.paragraphs = this.$el.attributes.originaldata.value.split('//')
    this.paragraphs.push('')
}
```

This does not with strings containing double quotes or html tags. I have tried binding to a prop using single quoted json_encoded data however this output breaks the prop-parsing in the browser and leaves bits of html and data scattered in the DOM.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hang encoded data from DOM elements and decode the content within a Vue component lifecycle hook.

```
// consider some arbitrary data passed from a Laravel controller containing HTML tags.
$data = '<form id="test"></form><button form="test" formaction="javascript:alert(1)">X</button>';

// echo the data within a blade layout or page element. CSRF tokens are often passed over this way.
<meta content="{{ base64_encode($data) }}" name="encoded">

// when your Vue component loads you can then access the DOM
export default {
  mounted () {
    const data = document.querySelector('meta[name="encoded"]').content

    alert(atob(data))
  }
}
```

[Here's a basic demo with vanilla PHP / JavaScript](https://www.tehplayground.com/41CydeC6ZJizhBeK)